# outlook can't search mail with subject in Japanese

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, unicode, email-client

Microsoft tell us that

> Microsoft Outlook supports Unicode and provides full support for multilingual data.

but today, when I search for my message with this subject "FW: １月分課題対応のお願い" (Sure that I have it in my mail box) My Outlook 2010 tell me that

> No match found for "FW: １月分課題対応のお願い"

Please give me some suggest about **how to make Outlook to search mails with Japanese subject properly?**
Best regards!
[image: No match found for "FW: １月分課題対応のお願い"]

Comment: Have you added the language through `file - options - language - add additional editing language` ?

Comment: yes I do, I've enabled Japanese, except that I didn't install Proofing Language Pack cause of microsoft tell me that Language Pack cost me $25 for these things, and I don't care about them, I just need to **read & find** my japanese mails  

 - Display in Japanese
 - Help in Japanese
 - Proofing tools for Japanese and English

![i've installed japanese][1]


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/w4wKz.png